# Setting pom version through Jenkins in a multi-module maven project

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml

I have a multi-module maven project which contains the same project version defined on every pom.
`<version>1.0.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT<\version>`

I use maven `apache-maven-2.2.1`

Everytime we have a new branch, a release or the need to update the version, we use a command to change all versions and commit it.

For curiosity, here is the command for find and replace:
`find . -type f -name pom.xml -print | xargs perl -pi -e 's@>'$version'<@>'$newVersion'<@g'`

By working this way, I have conflicts everytime I merge two versions on every pom, because the versions are always different.

**VERSION 1:** 1.0.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
**VERSION 2:** 1.0.0.0.0-FEATURE-SNAPSHOT

With subversion, I could easily solve those conflicts by using the mine-conflict option, which merges every modification that wasn't made in the same line and accept my version for all conflicts.

Unfortunately, git doesn't work this way and the most I can do is use something like "mine-full" (which accepts my version of the entire file - even non-conflicts) or "theirs-full" (which accepts their version of entire file), that could leave something from the file I choose to ignore.

I decided to put a static version (or a variable) on every pom of every version, which I was going to set everytime I had to use a mvn command.

I have four types of poms in my project and they are arranged as follow:

POM 1)
**projectName/main/super-parent/pom.xml**

```
<project ...>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com.company.product.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>company-product-super-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    ...
</project>
```

POM 2)
**projectName/main/module_A/fontes/components/pom.xml**

```
<project ...>
    <parent>
        <groupId>br.com.company.product.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>company-product-super-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    ...
    <groupId>br.com.company.product.moduleA</groupId>
    <artifactId>company-moduleA</artifactId>
    <name>Company PRODUCT - company-moduleA</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
```

POM 3) **projectName/main/module_A/fontes/components/parent/pom.xml**

```
<project ...>
    <parent>
        <groupId>br.com.company.product.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>company-product-super-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    ...
    <groupId>br.com.company.product.moduleA</groupId>
    <artifactId>company-moduleA-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Company Product - company-moduleA-parent</name>
    <description>Company ModuleA</description>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>br.com.company.product.moduleA</groupId>
                <artifactId>company-moduleA-submoduleA1</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
            ...
            </dependency>
```

POM 4)
**projectName/main/module_A/fontes/components/dir1/dir2/(...)/pom.xml**

```
<project ...>
    <parent>
        <groupId>br.com.company.product.moduleA</groupId>
        <artifactId>company-moduleA-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <name>Company PRODUCT - company-moduleA-submoduleA1</name>
    <description>Company ModuleA SubmoduleA1.</description>
    <artifactId>company-moduleA-submoduleA1</artifactId>
    <groupId>br.com.company.product.landbase</groupId>
```

What strategy I could use to avoid conflicts while merging two versions in the above scenario that would work on Jenkins?

Comment: Really using Maven 2.2.1 ? You know that [Maven 2.2.1 is End Of Life](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html). Second use Maven 3.2.X and you can use a property as version...http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/release-notes.html#Continuous_delivery_friendly_versions_MNG-5576

Comment: @khmarbaise, Thanks for the sugestion :-)
Sorry for the late reply, but I'm no longer working with the team that was having this problem... They have this link, though, in case someone answer it